# next.js and webpack resolve.modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, webpack, next.js

I am building a React app using next.js, and I am playing around with the webpack config, in the `next.config.js` file.

Specifically, I'd like to have nicer imports using webpack's `resolve.modules` config.

However, when I add the following line in the `next.config.js` file :

`config.resolve.modules
    .concat(['styles','static','components','imports'])`

and then
`import FooBar from 'components/index/FooBar"`, for example in a `pages/index.js` file, it still won't work. `FooBar` is not found.

The component exists, and the import works fine if I use a relative path. However I'd like to have nicer imports, and I know it is possible with webpack (see `react-boilerplate` for example).

Am I doing something wrong with webpack ? Maybe it's a real bug ?

Answer (score 3):

Check the [NextJS example with-absolute-imports](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-absolute-imports)

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
   webpack (config, options) {
       config.resolve.alias['components'] = path.join(__dirname, 'components')
       return config
    }
}
```

Alternatively, should work by adding this to `next.config.js` file:

`config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'));`

(and it doesn't require any babel plugin)

Answer (score 1):

`resolve.modules` will look into the directories you configured for the modules you import. So when import `components/index/FooBar` it will look in:

```
styles/components/index/FooBar
static/components/index/FooBar
components/components/index/FooBar
imports/components/index/FooBar
```

A relative path looks further, but that's not relevant here and the path remains the same, just climbing up the directory tree (see [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)).

Presumably none of these paths match your component. To get `component/index/FooBar` you need to import just `index/FooBar`.

```
import FooBar from 'index/FooBar';
```

Comment: This does not work yet but your point is correct, I'll try to investigate. 
Next.js devs propose to use `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to set up the root, though I don't really like it.